# I cant access another users table within java application

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm using oracle database 12c. 1 database with two schemas (users) one user is called `PROD` the second one `CREDIT`. I'm connected to database, using ojdbc (simple java application) as user `PROD` when i try to execute SQL query, which selects data from table owned by second user `CREDIT`.

I'll get error

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00942
```

Now when i connect to database using SQL Developer and run this query it works fine.
Select looks like this

```
SELECT C.USER FROM CREDIT.USERS C
```

In view "all_objects" I did found this table owned by user `CREDIT` and user `PROD`(both users have same structure but different data). Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Which user do you use to connect from SQL Developer?

Comment: Im using "prod" user

Comment: Are you 100% sure about that? Please record the query and the logged in user from ojdbc and also from SQL Developer. I am pretty sure you will find a difference (i.e. query not the same or not the same user that is logged in).

Comment: In SQL Developer, try "set role none" and run your query. It should fail. Due to your error message you are hitting the PLSQL engine? You need direct object grants (not via role) in order for the PLSQL engine to access the objects.

Comment: Or a different database; or with different (or no) roles, if the privileges aren't granted directly.